# Issues with creating an app wide config class

Tags: python

I have created two python modules to demonstrate a common problem i seem to have developing python apps.

test_config.py

```
import do_something

class TestConfig:

  _conf = {
    
    "test_case": 'Goodbye',
  }


  @staticmethod
  def get_config(name):
    return TestConfig._conf[name]

  @staticmethod
  def set(name, value):
      TestConfig._conf[name] = value

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(TestConfig.get_config('test_case'))   # prints Goodbye
    TestConfig.set('test_case', 'Hello')  
    print(TestConfig.get_config('test_case'))   # Prints Hello
    do_something.say_something()    # prints Goodbye?

    # Why does do_something print Goodbye- expected Hello
```

do_something.py

```
from test_config import TestConfig

def say_something():

    text = TestConfig.get_config('test_case')
    print(text)
```

Could someone explain why **do_something.say_something()** prints out Goodbye and not Hello?   And maybe the best way to create a global config class to access global variables.  I keep running into similar problems as well as circular imports. I need to set some config variables at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put this one line:

```py
print(id(TestConfig))
```

like this:

```py
import do_something


class TestConfig:
    _conf = {

        "test_case": 'Goodbye',
    }

    @staticmethod
    def get_config(name):
        return TestConfig._conf[name]

    @staticmethod
    def set(name, value):
        TestConfig._conf[name] = value


print(id(TestConfig))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(TestConfig.get_config('test_case'))  # prints Goodbye
    TestConfig.set('test_case', 'Hello')
    print(TestConfig.get_config('test_case'))  # Prints Hello
    do_something.say_something()  # prints Goodbye?
```

and this

```py
from test_config import TestConfig

print(id(TestConfig))


def say_something():

    text = TestConfig.get_config('test_case')
    print(text)
```

We only put 2 lines, so it should print out 2 of same ID right?

```
1700517329968
1700517329968
1700517331888
Goodbye
Hello
Goodbye
```

It is in fact called 3 times, and 3rd one actually has different id! So it has different `TestConfig`.

Logic is:

Main script(test_config.py) imports `do_something.py`
`do_something.py` imports `test_config.py` as *module*!
(`if __name__ == "__main__":` is now false so that block doesn't run)

Honestly I am not 100% sure how this doesn't count as circular import, but maybe import to `test_config.py` didn't import `do_something` again because it is already imported in namespace or it has some circular import resolving logic.

Suggested fix is, having a separate configuration python script or json/yaml any data format. This kind of circular import is not a good solution!